# Multiple Condition from 2 columns with different criteria

Tags: mysql

Need to Select rows from table where need to use 2 columns with different criteria

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `spec_property` (
`sp_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `spm_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `spec_value` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `spec_last_value` varchar(55) DEFAULT NULL,
  `product_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `spec_order_by` tinyint(2) unsigned DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=77 ;
ALTER TABLE `spec_property`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`sp_id`), ADD KEY `product_id` (`product_id`), ADD KEY `spec_value` (`spec_value`);
ALTER TABLE `spec_property`
MODIFY `sp_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=75;
INSERT INTO `spec_property` (`sp_id`, `spm_id`, `spec_value`, `spec_last_value`, `product_id`, `spec_order_by`) VALUES

(31, 23, 'Octa Core', NULL, 4, NULL),
(34, 26, '2048', 'MB', 4, NULL),
(35, 27, '8192', 'MB', 4, NULL),
(36, 28, '2048', 'MB', 4, NULL),
(69, 62, 'Android', NULL, 4, NULL),
(70, 63, '5', NULL, 4, NULL),
(71, 65, 'Yes', NULL, 4, NULL),
(72, 66, 'Yes', NULL, 4, NULL),
(73, 67, '32000', NULL, 4, NULL),
(74, 68, '25', 'fps', 4, NULL);
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/95329/13

```
SELECT distinct(product_id)
FROM `spec_property`
WHERE (spm_id = '62' AND spec_value IN ('Android' , 'Windows'))
    AND (spm_id = '27' AND spec_value BETWEEN 4096 AND 131072 )
```

If I use the 'OR' condition I can get this result:

( http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/95329/1 ). Actually i need to find product id's which are matches the filter options like

```
SELECT DISTINCT (product_id)
FROM spec_property
WHERE spm_id_62 IN ('Android', 'Windows')
    AND spm_id_27 BETWEEN 4096  AND 131072
    AND spm_id_26 BETWEEN 4096  AND 131072
```

Comment: spm_id *cant *  be 27 and 62 at same time

Comment: I dont see any question here. please read [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 
   And [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

this is a great place to start  http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 0):

You could try another set of parenthesis to structure the query

```
SELECT distinct(product_id)
FROM `spec_property`
WHERE ((spm_id = '62' AND spec_value IN ('Android' , 'Windows'))
OR (spm_id = '27' AND spec_value BETWEEN 4096 AND 131072 )
OR (spm_id = '26' AND spec_value BETWEEN 4096 AND 131072 ))
```

Comment: dont try to answer bad question. How spec_value can be string and number?

Comment: spec_value is always a string in the table, it just looks like a number :)

Comment: Yes, i may need glasses now